# Geolocation app that warns you when you are near something

Tags: iphone-app, geo-location

I would like an application that warns me when I am near hospitals or let's say parks(under 5 min walking distance) in notifies me. Assuming this generalization is feasible, what type of app would I need? iPhone would be the best. I'm in the USA. The price of all needs to be under $100.  I have a battery case on my phone so battery length isn't an issue.

Its okay if I have to program the locations in manually.

Comment: What you're looking for sounds like a geofencing application that works in reverse (normally, geofencing means you trigger something when leaving a defined radius around a given location, but you want the opposite).  You might have some luck searching for a generic geofencing application, as I would be rather surprised if you couldn't find one that can do this (though you may have to manually define the locations you want to avoid).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Manually defining locations although not ideal could work.

Comment: May I ask what is your final goal? That might give hints or keywords useful to think of apps that match. When you say "near", do you have in mind walking distances or driving distances? Is any tiny park OK?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul walking distance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include these details, thanks! :-)